# Android upload file to HttpServer using HTTP POST (File type: httppostedfilebase)

Tags: android

I need to upload file to server using httppost type. In server side they received the file in httppostedfilebase instance.

How to do this? Suggest me.

Comment: did you get the solution for this? i too need to send an HttpPostedFileBase item

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
url = new URL("http://....");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
outputStream.writeBytes(stufftosend);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```